Did the widow of Zarepath only believe after her son was resurrected in 1 Kings 17:24?
1 Kings 17:22-24
22  And the Lord heard the voice of Elijah; and the soul of the child came into him again, and he revived.
23 And Elijah took the child, and brought him down out of the chamber into the house, and delivered him unto his mother: and Elijah said, See, thy son liveth.
24 And the woman said to Elijah, Now by this I know that thou art a man of God, and that the word of the Lord in thy mouth is truth.
It wasn’t until after Elijah gave the widow her son, alive that she said:
“Now by this I know that thou art a man of God, and that the word of the Lord in thy mouth is truth”
But prior to that he told her
14 For thus saith the Lord God of Israel, The barrel of meal shall not waste, neither shall the cruse of oil fail, until the day that the Lordsendeth rain upon the earth.
15 And she went and did according to the saying of Elijah: and she, and he, and her house, did eat many days.
This was truth from Elijah’s mouth/Word of the Lord and it happened.
I asked a separate question about the widow of Zarepath but as I’m reading the story again, I see this was said.
Was she only grateful/ full of belief because of this resurrection?

There is not enough evidence to conclude whether the widow at Zarephath was faithful to God during the time Elijah was with her.
Jesus mentioned her in Luke 4:25-26 NIV

25 I assure you that there were many widows in Israel in Elijah’s time, when the sky was shut for three and a half years and there was a severe famine throughout the land. 26 Yet Elijah was not sent to any of them, but to a widow in Zarephath in the region of Sidon. (NIV)

Zarephath, identified as the modern town of Sarafand, is located between Tyre and Sidon in Phoenicia. The Phoenicians practiced a polytheistic religion, with Baal being one of their most prominent deities. Jesus' mention of the widow suggests she was a gentile, not an Israelite. Further evidence of her gentile status is found in her response to Elijah in 1 Kings 17:12, where she refers to the God of Israel as "your God" rather than "my God".

12 “As surely as the Lord your God lives,” she replied, “I don’t have any bread—............" (NIV)

Her polytheistic beliefs allowed her to trust that the God of Elijah, through him, would save her son's life, as she witnessed the miracle of endless flour and oil provided through Elijah. Throughout the account, the widow always regarded Elijah as the agent of his God, and her gratitude was directed towards Elijah rather than God.
1 Kings 17:24 NIV

Then the woman said to Elijah, “Now I know that you are a man of God and that the word of the Lord from your mouth is the truth.”

The first miracle served to sustain Elijah during his stay with the widow. The second miracle, however, was more appropriated seen as God's response to Elijah's prayer in 1 King 17:20-21, rather than a result of the widow's faith in God.

20 Then he cried out to the Lord, “Lord my God, have you brought tragedy even on this widow I am staying with, by causing her son to die?” 21 Then he stretched himself out on the boy three times and cried out to the Lord, “Lord my God, let this boy’s life return to him!”

On the bright side, the widow came to realize that the God of Israel was more powerful than Baal, the God of Phoenicians.

This story begins with a description of a famine brought about by Elijah's cursing the land in God's name. Before the story of the resurrection of the widow's son, we are told a story of the widow's family being fed through another miracle, as the OP mentions. Let's follow the narrative from the point that Elijah asks for a crust of bread:

As the Lord, your God, lives, I have nothing baked; there is only a
handful of flour in my jar and a little oil in my jug. Just now I was
collecting a few sticks, to go in and prepare something for myself and
my son; when we have eaten it, we shall die.” 13 Elijah said to her,
“Do not be afraid. Go and do as you have said. But first make me a
little cake and bring it to me. Afterwards you can prepare something
for yourself and your son. 14 For the Lord, the God of Israel, says:
The jar of flour shall not go empty, nor the jug of oil run dry, until
the day when the Lord sends rain upon the earth.” 15 She left and did
as Elijah had said. She had enough to eat for a long time—he and she
and her household. 16 The jar of flour did not go empty, nor the jug
of oil run dry, according to the word of the Lord spoken through
Elijah.

The text does not describe the widow's feeling here, but it is safe to presume both that she was grateful for this miracle and full of belief in Elijah as a man of God. So the answer to the OP's question is no, she did not believe only her son was resurrected. Her statement "by this I know" should be taken as a confirmation of her earlier faith.

Awesome, thanks!

Elijah was the worker of two miracles on behalf of the widow of Zarephath as recorded in 1 Kings 17:

supplying an endless source of oil and flour - but first she had to feed Elijah with the last of her supplies
raising the widow's son from the dead

Now, while the raising of the widow's son from the dead appears (and probably was) a greater miracle than the first, in a sense, the widow had to exercise greater faith for the first miracle because she risked her life to allow Elijah to perform it.
By contrast, the second miracle involved no personal risk.
Thus, it appears that the widow exercised greater faith for the first miracle than the second.  However, the second miracle greatly confirmed the widow's faith as she expresses in the text quoted by the OP.
